# Kibana asking for credentials

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, credentials

I set up a Kibana server that is accesing an External ElasticServer Datasource.  Nignx is on top, and I access Kibana through it.

On the initial config, I set up the credentials of Kibana using:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users kibanaadmin
```

Then I was able to access the Kibana Web Console, and see it running.  However, the external elasticServer was not configured, so I edited the kibana.yml file to point that external ElasticServer.

```
elasticsearch.url: "https://bluemix-sandbox-dal-9-portal0.dblayer.com:18671/"
elasticsearch.username: "admin"
elasticsearch.password: "mypass"
```

When I restarted Kibana,  it was able to connect to the elasticsearch server, and in fact it seems that it wrote an entry on the index there.

However, now I am asked for some credentials to get connected to the Kibana Web interface. They are not the kibanaadmin I set up previously, or the ones on elasticsearch database. Which credentials should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not running `Kibana` from the wrong ES instance and both `Kibana` and `Nginx` are running on the same server. Haven't tried it out personally but then the below links could be handy.

- [Enabling Kibana Authentication with Nginx](https://mahi130.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/enabling-kibana-authentication-with-nginx/)
- [Securing Elasticsearch, Kibana with nginx](http://www.ragingcomputer.com/2014/02/securing-elasticsearch-kibana-with-nginx)
- [Git- Kibana with Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://gist.github.com/mmetince/b0d44cc14e4c4c10cd64)